# Can I get a Tourist Schengen visa if I'm unemployed?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, austria

I'm quitting my job this month to take a break for a couple of months. I want to travel to Austria for a short holiday (a week maybe) and was wondering if getting a Tourist visa would be a challenge?

Will it be a problem since I will be unemployed at the time of applying for the visa?

I'm Indian and while I can show a reasonable bank balance and a definite travel plan (flight and hotel booking), just wondered if I'd need anything further.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: It probably depends on how much money you have, but likely you won't.  @GregHewgill seems to be interested in the possibility that you don't require a Schengen visa, which would change your prospects considerably.

Comment: Besides your nationality, a sense of how much savings you saved will probably help the wise ones here evaluate your application.

Comment: I don't need a visa for Schengen countries, but for other countries a clear, definite travel plan seems to help. Of course, the cost of the plan has to be reasonable relative to your savings and/or income.

Comment: Applying for the visa before you quit your job is another tack you could take. While you could, of course, be refused at the border if they don't think you're likely to return home, you're unlikely to get too many questions, especially as a visa-holder.

Answer (score 8):

It is impossible to say. Granting or denying a visa is often a subjective decision made by a consular employee and not based on well-defined rules leading to a 'yes' or 'no' decision.

Assuming that you have enough savings to finance your holiday, in case of a Schengen visa you are required to produce further documentation, e.g.:

> 'information enabling an assessment of the applicant’s intention to
>   leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa
>   applied for' - [Regulation (EC) No 810/2009](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN), article 14 1(d)

Basically, the examining officer will try to assess your ties to your home country and the risk of you stay illegaly in the Schengen area after the expiration of your visa. Being unemployed clearly counts against you, but if you e.g. have a good standing in the labour market of your home country and are likely to find a new job without much problems, being unemployed itself does not automatically cause a visa application to be rejected.